Error with iOS permissions in React Native: 'RNPermissions' module not found
I'm developing a React Native app using TypeScript, and I'm currently implementing permissions handling, particularly for iOS. However, I keep encountering the following error:
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissions' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary. Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["PlatformConstants","LogBox","SourceCode",...]}
I've already checked that the react-native-permissions package is installed in my projects I thought it was an incompatible version so I updated it and got version 4.1.5
"react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5"
I've tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it, but the error persists.
